# Calling MATLAB using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, matlab

I want to call matlab functions using VB.NET. I have referenced the *MATLAB Application* through COM. but I still get an error when using the Execute property:

System.MissingMemberException:“Public member 'Execute' on type 'DIMLApp' not found.”

Does anyone know what is the cause of this?